# calling a dll method but it is saying "is a field but is used like a type"

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use kernel32.dll and need to create my own dll for this i have created DllImp.cs code and want to use these methods in another file such as pipe.cs but i am getting an errors such as

```
CreateNamedPipe is a method but is used like a type.
PipeName is a field but is used like a type
PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX is a field but is used like a type
PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE  is a field but is used like a type
```

My code is:

```
//DllImp.cs code
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MessageManagerServer {
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public sealed class DllImports {
           [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateNamedPipe(
        String lpName,                              // pipe name
        uint dwOpenMode,                            // pipe open mode
        uint dwPipeMode,                            // pipe-specific modes
        uint nMaxInstances,                         // maximum number of instances
        uint nOutBufferSize,                        // output buffer size
        uint nInBufferSize,                         // input buffer size
        uint nDefaultTimeOut,                       // time-out interval
        IntPtr pipeSecurityDescriptor);             // SD
  public const uint PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX       = 0x00000003;
    //public const uint PIPE_TYPE_BYTE           = 0x00000000;
    public const uint PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE        = 0x00000004;
    //public const uint PIPE_READMODE_BYTE       = 0x00000000;
    public const uint PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE    = 0x00000002;
    public const uint PIPE_WAIT                = 0x00000000;

    public const uint NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER     = 0xffffffff;
    public const uint NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT = 0x00000000;

    public const int  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE     = -1;
    public const uint ERROR_IO_PENDING         = 997;
    public const uint PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES = 255;

    public DllImp() {
    }
}
```

Here is pipe.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public class Pipe
{
    private string PipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\Honeywell";
    public IntPtr Handle;
    Handle = DllImp.CreateNamedPipe(PipeName,DllImp.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                               DllImp.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE     |         
                               DllImp.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |         
                               DllImp.PIPE_WAIT,                      
                               1,                                        
                               0,                                         
                               0,                                        
                               1000,                                      
                               IntPtr.Zero);

}
}
```

Comment: And what is `DllImp`'s implementation?

Comment: Should that be `DllImports.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` etc?

Comment: Does that code for DllImp.cs compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initalize the `Handle` field like that, you're trying to access an instance field during initialization when you do:

```
 public IntPtr Handle;
 Handle = ...
```

This isn't allowed as you could potentially be accessing the field before it has been initialized.

Try doing it all in one go:

```
public IntPtr Handle = DllImp.CreateNamedPipe(PipeName,DllImp.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                           DllImp.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE     |         
                           DllImp.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |         
                           DllImp.PIPE_WAIT,                      
                           1,                                        
                           0,                                         
                           0,                                        
                           1000,                                      
                           IntPtr.Zero);
```

You could also move the initialization into the class contructor as in Marcs answer which is cleaner IMO.

```
public Pipe()
{
    Handle = ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I:

- changed all `DllImp` to `DllImports` (because that is what the class is called)
- moved the `Handle =` code into a constructor (could also have used a field-initializer, but this seemed to preserve the intent of the code)

and it compiled fine.

```
public Pipe()
{
    Handle = DllImports.CreateNamedPipe(PipeName,
                       DllImports.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                       DllImports.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |
                       DllImports.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |
                       DllImports.PIPE_WAIT,
                       1,
                       0,
                       0,
                       1000,
                       IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

(also renamed the constructor in `DllImports` to `DllImports`)

Full code: http://pastie.org/8555683